# _TENSOR_LIKE_TYPES = tuple() def is_dense_tensor_like(t): return isinstance(t, _TENSOR_LIKE_TYPES)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

i asked about this code, it works previously well but now it out the following error. any one can tell me why it make this error

```
KerasModel = keras.models.Sequential([
            keras.layers.Conv2D(100,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(s,s,3)),
            keras.layers.Conv2D(50,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.MaxPool2D(4,4),
            keras.layers.Conv2D(120,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),    
            keras.layers.Conv2D(80,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),    
            keras.layers.Conv2D(50,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.MaxPool2D(4,4),
            keras.layers.Flatten() ,    
            keras.layers.Dense(120,activation='relu') ,    
            keras.layers.Dense(100,activation='relu') ,    
            keras.layers.Dense(50,activation='relu') ,        
            keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5) ,            
            keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='softmax'),])



_TENSOR_LIKE_TYPES = tuple()  def is_dense_tensor_like(t):    return isinstance(t, _TENSOR_LIKE_TYPES)
```

Answer (score 0):

When error description include '_TensorLike', then most likely it is due to mixing functions from `keras` and `tf.keras` in the code. Due to some compatibility related issues, it will throw an error similar to the one you are noticing.

Check the following GitHub issue where I resolved the issue similar to you. That GutHub issue has complete code also for your reference. [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39817) is the GitHub issue.